# Display x axis properly on stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

Hey so I'm having difficulty with the positioning of my stacked bar chart. It's showing up, I'm just having difficulty declaring it's x axis. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E2HST/

```
var xTimeScale = d3.time.scale().
domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
.range([0, width]);
```

is obviously part of the problem, I pulled code and have unfortunately fallen into the trap of not fully understanding it.

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate("+xTimeScale(d.date)+",0)"
})
```

I've tried swapping in d.year for d.date seeing as there is no more d.date but it's throwing up errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the objects in your `data` array do not have a `date` key, so your `xTimeScale` domain is undefined.  An easy way to correct this would be to create this key for each data item:

```
data.forEach( function(d) { d.date = new Date(d.year, 0, 1); });
```

Which creates the date as January 1st of the `year` variable.  This basically solves your x-axis problem.

I would, however, suggest that your data would be better suited to using an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales), since you only have yearly data.

A couple of other small things:

- Your x-axis definition has way too many ticks, consider changing this
- Consider adding css styles for `.axis` elements, to improve readability

An updated fiddle with these slight changes is at http://jsfiddle.net/E2HST/1/

Comment: Thanks so much. That helped, though only 4 are displaying - not all 5. I updated the x-axis to show the proper ticks. It seems the first element is hidden on the x-axis and the last one the y. Thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/E2HST/2/

Comment: your scale definition here is the problem, if you look closely you'll see the bar for 2013 just barely on the right of the svg area.  your scale has the domain of [2009,2013], and the bottom left of each bar starts at the scale position for that year, you can see this easily by removing the code that translates your axis text.  To fix this, I would again recommend switching to an ordinal scale, it has built in functionality to account for bars and spacing, etc.